# Boto3 ApiGateway get_resource

Tags: aws-api-gateway, boto3

I have an api gateway with the following url:

```
 https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test/environment?myId=test_
```

and I want to use the boto3 lib to ask for my resource.

```
client = boto3.client('apigateway', region_name='us-west-2')
resp = client.get_resource(restApiId=xxxxx, resourceId=???, embed=myId=test_)
```

Where do I have to enter my api-key and what`s my resourceId for the "get_resource" call?

In a second step, I want to create a domain name "myapi.example.com" to replace the restApiId and the stage "https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test/".

How do I have to call the boto3.get_resource() method with a domain name?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call [get_resources](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.get_resources) to get a list of resource id's:

---

```
response = client.get_resources(
    restApiId='string'
)
print(json.dumps(response, indent=2, default=str))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the AWS CLI installed, then you can use it to configure your credentials file:

```
aws configure
```

Alternatively, you can create the credential file yourself. By default, its location is at ~/.aws/credentials:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = YOUR_ACCESS_KEY
aws_secret_access_key = YOUR_SECRET_KEY
```

NOTE: EC2 instance already have access.

YOU CAN NOT call get_resource with the domain name